# is it possible to store data into variable at controller?

Tags: laravel-5.4

```
**trying to pass the data in database into variable and then insert to another table**
```

$query = DB::table('students')->where('studno', $request->input('stud_id'))->get();

**How?**

[This is student table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPhr1.png)

[and this is attendance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROFwJ.png)

i want to copy that row to another table and also add time in

Comment: Can you ask what do you wont do. Other model structure or any other info for help you

Comment: i cant transfer data from database into variable so i can insert it to another table. please help me

Comment: Show another table structure

Comment: sorry Davit i already edit. please see picture above

Comment: I add post. When try it ask me about result

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works fine, but all remained columns you must be specify yourself

```
$students = DB::table('students')->where('studno', $request->input('stud_id'))->get();
$data = [];
foreach ($students as $student) {
    $singleData['studno'] = $student->studno;
    $singleData['batch'] = $student->batch;
    ......
    // other column specify yourself
    $data[] = $singleData;
}

if ($data) {
    $isSavedAttendances = DB::table('attendances')->insert($data);
    // $isSavedAttendances must be true or false 
}
```